# Facing problem with serialization

Tags: c#

HI 
Here is my scenario where i have to serialize an object to a file.

I am using binaryformatter to serialize an object as,

```
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream1, object);
```

I am writting GetObjectData() as follows,

```
            serinfo.AddValue("string1",objecta);
            serinfo.AddValue("string2",objectb);
            serinfo.AddValue("string3",objectc);
```

I am serializing 2 lists list1, list2 in objectb. sizeof the lists vary time to time.(each list may also have 100000 elements.. means number of elements in list influence the size of the stream).so, when i serialize the object, my stream size should not exceed 10mb and If it exceeds i should write in another stream. simply to say, if size exceeds 10mb, i should have one more stream and each stream should be in following format

```
stream1 --> objecta,(objectb)some n values in list,objectc
stream2 --> objecta,(objectb)values in list from n+1 to some m,objectc
 ..
streamn --> ........
```

each stream size should be limited to 10mb..

Please provide me some clues to do this..
thanks in advance..
(first of all thanks for reading this large qn..:P)

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd serialize my objects into a MemoryStream, then check if adding it into the current filestream would exceed 10MB, and start a new stream before writing if it would.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this directly, because only one stream can be passed to `Serialize` method. Either use `MemoryStream` as target and then manually spread to streams or break initial object into pieces before serialization

Comment: I mean, how can i spread without knowing size of each subobject?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you separate the splitting of the stream from the serialization.  That is, serialize to one stream (of whatever length necessary), and split that stream into 10Mb chunks separately.

Comment: Wouldn't that approach either double the memory requirement for the objects to be serialized, or cause some unneeded IO operations?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You could serialize to memory first and then split the data as your write to a filestream - so no extra IO.  And if you were using the MemoryStream as a buffer - reading from the start and writing to the end in the same operation - you don't need to keep all of the data in memory.  There would be some overhead, but it certainly shouldn't double the required memory.  So, in summary: when I said "separately", that doesn't necessarily mean "one after the other" - just in separate pieces of code.

Comment: After writting to a single stream, how can i know the length of each subobject? (Here i need both objecta and objectc in every stream).